# Django - Bootstrap4 - DateRangePicker - django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus

Tags: django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

Firstly, i am not an ultra expert about Django objects or structures, i learn with numerous and various curses and i try during the development of my website to reach the must clear and efficient code in my Django project.

Now i try to make a date range picker in `bootstrap 4` (4.1.3)

I will obtain the same result as this tool [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus), i trying to follow the example code but i dont know how to add this tool on my django project.

For now i cant successfully render the `daterangepicker` on the template.

I share the files that concerns by this tool.

## models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    start_month = models.DateField()
    end_month = models.DateField()
    start_year = models.DateField()
    end_year = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## forms.py

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import TimePickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DateTimePickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import MonthPickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import YearPickerInput

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'start_date', 'end_date',
            'start_time', 'end_time',
            'start_datetime', 'end_datetime',
            'start_month', 'end_month',
            'start_year', 'end_year',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'start_date': DatePickerInput(options={'format': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'debug': True}).start_of('event active days'),
            'end_date': DatePickerInput(options={'format': 'MM/DD/YYYY'}).end_of('event active days'),
            'start_datetime': DateTimePickerInput(options={'debug': True}).start_of('event active dtime'),
            'end_datetime': DateTimePickerInput().end_of('event active dtime'),
            'start_time': TimePickerInput(options={'debug': True}).start_of('event active time'),
            'end_time': TimePickerInput().end_of('event active time'),
            'start_month': MonthPickerInput().start_of('active month'),
            'end_month': MonthPickerInput().end_of('active month'),
            'start_year': YearPickerInput().start_of('active year'),
            'end_year': YearPickerInput().end_of('active year'),
}
```

## views.py

```
@login_required
def visual_general(request):

    ....
    # get data for the table of django-tables2 and other stuff
    ....

    # Get data
    data = create_data_table_general(samples, references, strains, analyzepipelines, sts, id_access_list)


    # Add data to the table
    table = GeneralTable(data)

    form_date_range = EventForm()

    return render(request, 'visual/visual_general.html', {'table': table, 'form_date_range': form_date_range})
```

## urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Library Django
from django.conf.urls import url

# Inner functions
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^visual/General', views.visual_general,     name="visual_general"),
]
```

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}MySite{% endblock %}</title>

        {% load static %}

        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/menu.css' %}" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" />
        {% endblock %}

        {% block css %}
            <!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
            <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
            <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
            <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block bootstrap_css %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
        {% endblock %}



        {% block bootstrap_js %}
                <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery3.min.js' %}"></script>
                <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
                <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <section id="content">
            {% block content %}
                <h1>No content set</h1>
            {% endblock %}
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

## visual_general.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Visual of data {% endblock%}

{% block content %}


<div id="form">

    <form
        id="test"
        action="{% url 'visual_general' %}"
        method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div
            class="well"
            style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px 20px 0 40px; position: relative; top: 0; background: #B8C1C8;">

            <div class="row">
                {{form_date_range.media}}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <center>
                            <input
                                class="button"
                                type="submit"
                                value="Filter" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone can help me to add a date range picker or for any tips or comment on my code.

Comment: Are you having this issue still now? or it has resolved?

Comment: I changed the tool to have a daterange picker.

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong with your setup? You don't have `form.as_p` in your template, no the form does not show up.

Comment: indeed,  if i retry to use `django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus` i will see this point. Thanks.